# How to remove a Mutex on WinXP

Tags: c#, mutex

We have a Mutext in our C# .Net Application created by following statement:

> new Mutex(true, "MutexName", out
>   pobjIOwnMutex);

Actually we have no problem with it, but since a while the Application can not take the ownership of this mutex anymore. This happens only on my developer pc. If I change the mutex name it is no problem, so I assume that the mutex still exists somewhere in the system.

Is there a way to release this mutex in the system, or could there be another reason which this happens?

Thanks for help,
Enyra

Answer (score 0):

Is a previous instance of the program running? Have you checked for handle leaks? Try using a tool such as Process Explorer to see if any processes have a handle open to that mutex.

Comment: No there is no instance of the program running, it also happens after rebooting the system.

Comment: What do you mean by "can not take the ownership"? What exactly happens?

Comment: in the snippet I posted the constructor of mutex takes an "out" paremeter indicating whether a new mutex has been created or not. If propjIOwnMutex = false (what happens in my case) the system already has as a mutex with the given name. This is what I call take the ownership.